# Erro ao tentar inserir dados via formulario JSF- Erro BEAN

Tags: java, jsf, aplicação-web, sql-insert, java-bean

Estou começando a criar um aplicação WEB, utilizando JSF, porém
Tento inserir alguns dados através de um form e é exibido o erro abaixo:

> /usuario.xhtml @19,72 value="#{usuarioBean.email}": Target
>   Unreachable, identifier 'usuarioBean' resolved to null

Meu método salvar:

```
public String salvar(){
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        if(!this.senha.equalsIgnoreCase(this.confirmaSenha)){
            context.addMessage(null,new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Senha confirmada incorretamente",""));
            return "usuario";
        }
        //salva usuario
        return "sucesso";           
    }
```

Página Xhtml

Cadastro de Usuários

## Cadastro de Usuários

---

```
    <h:outputLabel value="e-Mail:" for="email" />
    <h:inputText id="email" label="email" value="#{usuarioBean.email}" />

    <h:outputLabel value="CPF:" for="cpf" />
    <h:inputText id="cpf" label="cpf" value="#{usuarioBean.cpf}" />

    <h:outputLabel value="Senha:" for="senha" />
    <h:inputSecret id="senha" label="Senha" value="#{usuarioBean.senha}" required="true"/>

    <h:outputLabel value="Confirmar Senha:" for="confirmarsenha" />
    <h:inputSecret id="confirmarSenha" label="Confirmar Senha" value="#{usuarioBean.confirmaSenha}" required="true" />

    <h:outputText/>
    <h:commandButton action="#{usuarioBean.salvar}" value="Salvar" />
 </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
<hr />
</h:body>
```

Minha Classe Bean:

@ManagedBean(name="UsuarioBean")
@RequestScoped
public class UsuarioBean {

```
private String nome;
private String cpf;
private String senha;
private String confirmaSenha;

@ManagedProperty(value="#{param}")
private Map<String,String> parametros;

//Método de Operação
public String operacao(){
    //executa a operação
    return "resultado";

}

public String novo(){
    return "usuario";
}

//Getters e Setters
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}   
public String getCpf() {
    return cpf;
}
public void setEmail(String cpf) {
    this.cpf= cpf;
}
public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}
public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}
public String getConfirmaSenha() {
    return confirmaSenha;
}
public void setConfirmaSenha(String confirmaSenha) {
    this.confirmaSenha = confirmaSenha;
}

public String salvar(){
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if(!this.senha.equalsIgnoreCase(this.confirmaSenha)){
        context.addMessage(null,new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Senha confirmada incorretamente",""));
        return "usuario";
    }
    //salva usuario
    return "sucesso";           
}
```

}

Lib:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Na próxima farei com texto. Obrigado pela ajuda brother.

Comment: Usa CDI bean, JSF bean ? criou get/set para as propriedades ? aproveita e coloca todo manageBean.

Comment: Dilnei, uso JSF bean

Comment: Usa maven? ou adicionou as libs no classpath da app? pode adicionar a informação? o @Request scope vem deste import? 

```import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
```

Comment: Dilnei, não uso Maven. Adicionei as libs no classpath. Adicionei a img da lib na pergunta.
a anotação vem deste import:
 import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

Comment: Pior que eu não estou nem conseguindo debugar, para verificar se ele está entrando no método. Eu sou iniciante, e estou desenvolvendo essa aplicação através de um exemplo do livro.

Comment: Desculpe tantas perguntas mas se faz necessário, configurou o web.xml? e criou o arquivo de configuração do faces, faces-config.xml?

Answer (score 2):

O problema está aqui:

```
@ManagedBean(name="UsuarioBean")
```

Por padrão, o nome dos mbeans é o nome da classe com a inicial minúscula, mas você o sobrescreveu informando a inicial maiúscula. Como você está chamando "usuarioBean" na tua página, o mbean não é encontrado pois ele foi nomeado como "UsuarioBean". Modifica o name para "usuarioBean" e o mbean vai poder ser acessado na página xhtml.

Comment: Alterei o bean, mas deu o erro abaixo:

Não foi possível criar o bean gerenciado usuarioBean.  Os seguintes problemas foram encontrados:
 A propriedade parametros para o bean gerenciado usuarioBean não existe.

Comment: Giuliana Alterei o name do bean, e retirei o trecho 

@ManagedProperty(value="#{param}")
private Map<String,String> parametros;

aí deu certo,muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Ótimo! Marca como respondida :)